# If my Ehcache is configured with a TTL, do I need to check if a retrieved Element is expired?

Tags: java, ehcache

I can't find this anywhere in the Ehcache docs.

Right now I'm using this code to create and configure my `Cache`:

```
// Groovy syntax

def cacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration('stats', 1)
cacheConfig.timeToLiveSeconds = 2

def cache = new Cache(cacheConfig)
cache.initialise()
```

and this to retrieve data:

```
// Groovy syntax

def cachedElement = cache.get('stats')

if (cachedElement != null && ! cachedElement.isExpired()) {
    // use the cached data
} else {
    // get/generate the data and cache it
}

return cachedElement.value
```

I wrote this awhile ago, but looking at it now it seems kinda silly to have to check `Element.isExpired()` — that shouldn't be necessary, right? I mean, if an element is expired, then the cache shouldn't return it — right?

So I'm thinking I can remove that check — just hoping for a quick sanity check here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't have to perform this check. If you get a non-null element back, then it's not expired. It is odd that the javadoc doesn't mention this, right enough, and although I *have* read this somewhere, I can't find a reference to back up my answer.

Comment: thanks! I want to vote this answer up but it really needs a link first.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible that your cacheElement *could* actually be null then the null check is not enough. Simply returning null when something is expired is not always sufficient in that case. Ecache has no reliable way of determining if something is expired until it is accessed. You could set the following in the config:

```
<ehcache:config cache-manager="ehCacheManager">
  <!-- interval is in minutes -->
  <ehcache:evict-expired-elements interval="20"/>
</ehcache:config>
```

but there is always a chance that your access will fall within that interval. 
If you are absolutly certain that your values are *never* null, then you can drop the isExpired() call.

Comment: @user209024, I suspect *eviction* is more about memory management — which elements to delete when memory is tight — than expiration. Good point about nulls, though I doubt I'd ever bother storing them.

Comment: I have been bitten by the null elements - it was a error condition that was lost by assuming null ONLY meant expired or never inserted.